# Incrementing a class variable

Tags: ruby, class-variables

I have this code:

```
class Person
  @@instance_count = 0

  def initialize name
    @name = name
    @@instance_count += 1
  end
  def self.instance_count
    p "Instances created - #{@@instance_count}"
  end
end

person_1 = Person.new "first_name"
person_2 = Person.new "second_name"
person_3 = Person.new "third_name"

Person.instance_count
```

which outputs `"Instances created - 3"`.

I do not understand why `+=` in `initialize` increments `@@instance_count` and not resets it to `0` every time a new instance variable is created. What is happening when `@@instance_count` is not reset to `0` every time a new instance is created?

Comment: Because there's only one instance of that variable. No new ones are created. Probably you confuse class variables (`@@var`) with instance variables (`@var`)

Answer (score 3):

> A variable whose name begins with '@' is an instance variable of self.
>   An instance variable belongs to the object itself.
>
> ```
> @foobar
> ```
>
> A class variable is shared by all instances of a class and begins with '@@'.
>
> ```
> @@foobar
> ```

Here is the source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Instance_Variables

## EDIT

```
# This is a class
class Person
  @@instance_count = 0

  # This is the class constructor
  def initialize name
    @name = name
    @@instance_count += 1
  end

  def self.instance_count
    @@instance_count
  end
end

# This is an instance of Person
toto = Person.new "Toto"
# This is another instance of Person
you  = Person.new "Trakaitis"

p Person.instance_count # 2
```

`@@instance_count` is a `class variable` it is attached to the class itself, not to its instantiations. it's part of the class definition, such as the methods.
Let's say it is created and set to `0` once ruby has parsed your class code.

When you create a new instance of this class using `new` (`toto = Person.new "Toto"`), the class constructor will be called. So `@name` will be created as a local variable to the new instance, and `@@instance_count`, that has been set to 0 previously, will be recognized and incremented by `1`.